# anyone ever heard of simplexml parser error 544?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When I use:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXMLElement');
```

I get this error **"failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 544"**.

1. Fun fact `[1]`: it works just fine on localhost.
2. Fun fact `[2]`: 544 parser error does not seem to exist on the Reference Manual for libxml2.
3. Fun fact `[3]`: the xml file opens normally on any browser. file is intact.

Can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: **HTTP Error 544** is an Internal Server Error. It is not concerned with the SimpleXML Library. Check your server code for more details of why it is happening.

Comment: Error is with your **Server Side Code**. And is **NOT** with the XML or the library. Did you get it? `:)`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Praveen! But I can't find this error code in any documentation, isn't it weird?

Comment: Actually, yes it is **really weird**. I can't find this error code in HTTP too. What server are you using?

Comment: linux Apache: 2.4.16 Perl: 5.10.1

Comment: Can you check what you see in the Apache Error logs?

Comment: can't find it right now. I'll update when I get it.

Comment: Okay buddy. This is **super crazy**. Somehow let's solve it. `:)`

Comment: I checked the error code but nothing new came up. It shows exactly the same warnings displayed during the execution :( I'm trying to make my host solve this, but they're stuck lol

Comment: is it possible that the third party server is blocking me?

Comment: Could be. 5xx error is server side one.